# How can a variable declared in scala can be used by spark executors in cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning scala and spark and I have a requirement and I have some doubt on the approach that I have implemented to meet the requirement.
First I'll tell how my dataframe looks and what operation I want to perform on my dataframe.


How it looks

```
+-----------------+----------------------------+
|           Street|Total Passing Vehicle Volume|
+-----------------+----------------------------+
|      Kimball Ave|                       100  |
|      Ashland Ave|                       50   |
|         State St|                       110  |
|      Kimball Ave|                       40   |
|     Diversey Ave|                       60   |
|      Ashland Ave|                       70   |
```

As you can see there are some repeated Street names. So the requirement is to sum the total vehicle passed by each street and add a new column with the calculated sum


It should look like this

```
+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------+
|           Street|Total Passing Vehicle Volume|Total Vehicle|
+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------+
|      Kimball Ave|                       100  |       140   |
|      Ashland Ave|                       50   |       120   |
|         State St|                       110  |       110   |
|      Kimball Ave|                       40   |       140   |
|     Diversey Ave|                       60   |       60    |
|      Ashland Ave|                       70   |       120   |
```

I'm bgetting what I want but after reading some articles I discovered that my approach is not good as it will fail in ceratin situation.

**My approach**

```
var map: Map[String,Integer]= Map.empty;

  trafficDf.select(
    trafficDf.col("Street").cast("string"),
    trafficDf.col("Total Passing Vehicle Volume").cast("integer")
  ).foreach(r=>{
    if(!map.contains(r.get(0).toString)){
      map += r.get(0).toString -> r.get(1).asInstanceOf[Integer]
    }else{
      var m= map(r.get(0).toString);
      map += r.get(0).toString -> (m + r.get(1).asInstanceOf[Integer])
    }
  })
```

As you can see I have declaired a `Map` and iterating the `Street` and `Total Passing Vehicle Volume` column and checking if the Street column(individual record) is present in the map the update the value by adding with previous value with the current one else simply insert with the value.
But after reading some article I think it will fail when it will be deployed to cluster because this execution will be divided between multiple executors and the executors will not be having the `Map` instance with them so at the end map will not even populated.
Then I read about `Closure` which uses a free variable which will not be a part of the function. But the Map which I have declared is also a free variable(what i think).


Here I'm adding the column with value:

```
var func = udf( (s:String) => {
    val d= map.get(s);     //getting the the value from map for each record in Street column
    d
  } )

val newTrafficFd= trafficDf.select($"Street",$"Total Passing Vehicle Volume",func($"Street").as("Total Vehicle"))
  newTrafficFd.show(20);
```

Any enhancement or any suggestion? Will it work as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stone, you don't need to use RDDs nor UDFs for this. It can be achieved with a Window aggregation like this :

```
val trafficDf = Seq(
      ("Kimball Ave", 100),
      ("Ashland Ave", 50),
      ("State St", 110),
      ("Kimball Ave", 40),
      ("Diversey Ave", 60),
      ("Ashland Ave", 70)
    ).toDF("Street", "Total Passing Vehicle Volume")

trafficDf.withColumn("Total Vehicle", sum($"Total Passing Vehicle Volume").over(Window.partitionBy("Street")))
      .show()
```

Output :

```
+------------+----------------------------+-------------+
|      Street|Total Passing Vehicle Volume|Total Vehicle|
+------------+----------------------------+-------------+
| Ashland Ave|                          50|          120|
| Ashland Ave|                          70|          120|
|Diversey Ave|                          60|           60|
| Kimball Ave|                         100|          140|
| Kimball Ave|                          40|          140|
|    State St|                         110|          110|
+------------+----------------------------+-------------+
```

Explanation :

`Windowing / Analytical functions` is an ANSI SQL feature allowing to compute extra-aggregations based on row groups.

Spark has implemented this feature so it can easily be used within its DSL.

This feature allowed me to compute the `Total Vehicle` column as the sum of  `Total Passing Vehicle Volume` associated to each `Street` value.

You can learn more about windowing in general here :

https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/oracle-sql-analytical-functions-for-beginners-a-gentle-introduction-to-common-sql-window-functions/

or specifically for Spark :

http://queirozf.com/entries/spark-dataframe-examples-window-functions

Comment: oh my god what is this please tell me what you have done basically I'm from java background so I tried to solve this problem in logically way as what we do but these stuffs are completely new everyday i encounter new thing about spark. Can you please explain little what you have done

Comment: Sure, I'll add an explanation to the answer in a few minutes ;)

Comment: I'm learning spark through internet articles only where most of websites doesn't have whole contents about spark since you are a spark developer can you suggest me any resources it can be anything except PAID contents where I can explore things as many as i can

Comment: Unfortunately, general resource recommendations is forbidden in StackOverflow. I added specific links in my answer to help you with Windowing. You can retrieve more Spark SQL features in this documentation page : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features